# Does Flutter Secure Storage persist once the app closes?

Tags: flutter

I tried to store usernames and passwords after someone logged in successfully with Flutter Secure Storage, but I wasn't able to read the keys. Is this expected behavior or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Yes it saves once the app is closed. You can check the example app here: https://github.com/mogol/flutter_secure_storage/tree/develop/example This shows that keys can be created and once the app is closed and reopened, the keys are not wiped. If you share your code, we might be able to see what is wrong.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does. You'll have to share code so we can see what you're doing wrong. In the mean there is also another way as recommended by Flutter examples.

I've had a great experience using the [SharedPreferences](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences) plugin. It's easy to asign key-value pairs and retrieve them.

Answer (score 4):

It is expected behavior that data written in secure storage persists after app is closed. Data is written in KeyStore and KeyChain on Android and iOS, respectively.